# Java Recursive efficiency analysis

Tags: java, recursion

I need help creating an efficiency analysis for a method like this one below. I need to come up with:

1. Factors that influence runtime
2. What is being counted(comparisons, operations)?
3. Best/Worst Case
4. Big O Notation

Here's what I have so far:

1. array length
2. math operations
3. Worst Case and best case are the same, as the method will run the whole array, regardless of its contents
4. no idea

Let me know what you think.

Thanks

```
double sum(double[] array) {
    return recursiveSum(array, 0, array.length - 1);
}

double recursiveSum(double[] array, int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo == hi) {
        return array[lo];
    }

    int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
    double leftsum = recursiveSum(array, lo, mid);
    double rightsum = recursiveSum(array, mid+1, hi);
    return leftsum + rightsum;
}
```

Comment: I think it is final exam season.  Do you know the [master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)?

Comment: use loop to get sum of array, recursion is overkill

Comment: trustme, I would love to not have to use recursion, it's not my choice

Comment: BTW The big O is not something you measure, it is based on the scalability of an algorithm on an ideal machines, not based on how the algorithm performs on real machines.  90% of the time, you are much better off using a loop in Java than recursion.

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

1. array length
2. no idea
3. Worst Case and best case are the same, as the method will run the
   whole array, regardless of its contents
4. O(nlogn) (f(n)=2*f(n/2) -> f(n)=O(nlogn))